# Is there any way to ignore mapping character filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I setup the mapping character filter with mappings_path.
Is it possible to ignore the mapping in some special case when searching?
Thanks!

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html#analysis-mapping-charfilter

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch are you using? And can you elaborate on the special case that you are talking about?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you may use *multi-fields*. You can use multiple analyzers for them.Please check [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers). It would be great if you can give more details.